# Marvel don't get key

Tags: api, key

I have a Mac and I use Safari, I'm trying to connect to the Marvel API (developer.marvel.com), for this one I need to have a Key, when I click on 'Get Key' appear the "MARVEL API TERMS OF USE "and in the bottom of the web appear a button with" I ACCEPT THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS ABOVE. ", Okay, when I click on this button do not happen nothing and I can not get a key :( What is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I Have exactly the same issue for 2-3 weeks now. I've send them 2 emails but no one responded. I've also tried with 3 different browsers.

Comment: The same happens to me, I have sent an electronic mail and they do not respond :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. If you inspect the checkbox you'll see there is a hidden submit button right after the text. Delete the "display: none", click it and you're done.